# Re-rendering a particular component in Angular 2 release version

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-changedetection

I have two components: BuilderComponent and InputTextComponent.
With drag and drop I put a directive in the sortableList element of the BuilderComponent template. With the inspector I can see the directive appears in the sortablelist DOM element:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ul id="sortableList">
      <zbjfb-input-text></zbjfb-input-text>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I force the BuilderComponent to detect that the content of the template is changed since the last compile and then re-render the template with the new added directive so I can see the new compiled InputTextComponent.

BuilderComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'zbjfb-builder',
  template: '
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul id="sortableList">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  '

})
export class BuilderComponent  {}
```

InputTextComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'zbjfb-input-text',
  templateUrl: './input-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.css']
})
export class InputTextComponent {}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your drag'n'drop solution is HTML5 based, maybe you can make use of HostListener decorator from '@angular/core' to hack your drag and drop exchange logic:

Add something like this on your drop area component:

```
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) 
onDrop(event: any) {
    //do something             
}
```

And something like this on your draggable component:

```
@HostListener('dragstart', ['$event']) 
onDrag(event: any) {
    //do something
}
```

HostListeners provide you ways to implement conventional listeners for element events like onmousedown, onkeyup, ondrop, ondrag.

Then think of some logic to identifiy what's being dragged/dropped and change the drag area component model. Here's some functional code I've made inspired by W3Schools topic on drag'n'drop:

```
import { Component, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

// The draggable component
@Component({
    selector: 'dragme',
    template: `
        <div draggable="true">
            Drag {{name}}!
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        [draggable] {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-drag: element;
            -webkit-user-drag: element;
            background-color: #AAA; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            padding: 24px;
            margin: 12px;
        }
    `]
})
export class DragMe {

    @Input()
    name:string = "";

    @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDrag(event:any){        
        event.dataTransfer.setData("name",this.name);
    }
}

// The drop area component
@Component({
    selector: 'drop',
    template: `
        <div class="drop">
            Drop over me!
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .drop{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 24px;
        }
    `]
})
export class DropOverMe {

    items:string[] = [];

    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
    onDragover(event:any){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
    onDrop(event:any){
        event.preventDefault();        
        var name = event.dataTransfer.getData("name");                        
        this.items.push(name);
    }
}

// The functional example
@Component({
    selector: "drag-example",
    template: `
        <dragme name="Bob"></dragme>
        <dragme name="Alice"></dragme>
        <dragme name="Carl"></dragme>

        <drop></drop>
    `

})
export class DragExample{

}
```

Full code at: https://github.com/rafaelodon/angular2-html5-dragndrop-example